# Ionic 3 / Angular 5 App crashes within a (wanted) loop function

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

To describe the function i have in a simplified way, i want to download a large set of images, in my case ~ 50 units. I use a recursive attempt.

Therefore, i kick off everything in an outer function and repeat as long as every picture was downloaded. Image-source is loaded into an Image-object, and translated into Canvas to get the right src format to save. Additional info: I can not load them in a bunch, have to do it image by image.

After having loaded around half of the images, the app crashes. I assume it thinks being in a deadlock, which causes abortion. Any idea how to tell Ionic, that those situations should be ignored?

Tested on various Android-devices, so OS Versions (4.4 - 8.1) should not matter.

**CODE**

```
constructor(...) {
    this.downloadImage(this.images);
}   



downloadImage(images) {     
    ... downloadStuff...
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        var src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        saveImg(src);
        images.splice(0,1)
        if(images.length == 0) {
            alert("DONE!!");
        } else {
            this.downloadImage(results);
        }
    }
    img.src = images.photo_url;
}
```

**Memory**

[image: Memory]

**Android Studio Errorlog:**

A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0xd4502e96 in tid 23363 (Chrome_InProcRe), pid 23231 (ft.xxx)
E/SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer (SurfaceView - xxx.MainActivity#0) in layer parent (no-parent).

Comment: where do you save the images? ionic shouldn't crash when you do something for a long time. sounds to me like a memory issue (all imagedata somewhere in memory...)

Comment: I used https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library/  photo-library-plugin for cordova. I edited my code as well.

Comment: this is nice but didn't answer my question. You are recursivly calling your function, so the callstack grew. When you not save and dumb your images and references your memory would get eaten up. Use Studio or Xcode to run your app and watch the memory while you downloading

Comment: See my edited code + description for more information. I also checked my memory, which seems to be okay. Also reviewable within the image just added + 2 Lines of Android Studio error information